# When adding data to an Excel chart, the default for "Series values" is "={1}"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've never understood what this means. When you go to add a new data series to a chart in Excel, for "Series values" it reads "={1}" without the quotes. I always have to delete this. What is it for / what does it signify?

Answer (score 0):

Curly Braces denote an array constant in Excel. The series must contain data, so it defaults to `{1}`.

Comment: So it means 1 everywhere? i.e. no matter how many x values you have, all y values =1? It doesn't seem to behave that way...

Comment: @BenS. It's equivalent to selecting a single cell containing the value `1`.

Comment: So why doesn't it just read "=1"?

Comment: @BenS. Because they are not the same. `=1` is the number one, and `={1}` is a single-element array containing the number one. Try adding a series with just `=1` as the series values. You can't do it because Excel is expecting either a range or an array constant.